# Why XMLHttpRequest typeof response differs depending on OS

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is there a reason why on Windows (v7 - Chrome v43) when returning a PDF binary file back to an XMLHTTPRequest, the response type is a string, whereas on Mac  Chrome, the response is an object(arraybuffer).

The ajax call is to the same remote URL, from the same page.

To show an cut down example of the code, where params.url defines the pdf resource

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onload = function(evt) {
        console.log(typeof xhr.response)        
    };
    try {
      xhr.open('GET', params.url, true);
      xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';      
      xhr.send();
    } catch (e) {
      params.error( e);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please show us the HTTP headers of both requests? And what the `.responseType` of your xhr is (maybe just show us your code)?

Comment: well console.log of the 'typeof' the response yield 'string' and 'object' *the latter being a correct arraybuffer 

the request headers/response were identical, contenttype application/pdf, correct length present..

Comment: I didn't ask for `typeof xhr.response` (which is obvious from your description), but for `xhr.responseType`. Please show the minimal code that would let us reproduce your problem.

Comment: after xhr open(),  I am setting response type to arraybuffer..  xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer'

Comment: I created a work around by reacting differently depending on the typeof result.  But still,  I don't want to leave it without knowing why in Windows the response is interpreted differently.  Perhaps the XMLHttpRequest has a different implementation